# Detect click on option for React/MaterialUI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [MaterialUI's autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) - I can detect the value option value selected using the onChange event handler

```
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={this.state.items}
    onChange={this.onChangeFired.bind(this)}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Products" variant="outlined" />
)}/>
```

However, I cannot figure how to detect the event that is fired when the same option is selected again - onChange doesn't get fired in this situation

e.g. the event that would be fired if i click on "banana" again if "banana" is already selected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

API documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Use `onClose` that will provide you with reason `select-option`.

Comment: no.. onClose doesn't get called if you select the same option